# How to sync filters of a card with other graphics?

Tags: powerbi

I have a report with numbers of tickets of Ocomon. But I use Cards to show the number of tickets opened today, the number of tickets closed today, etc. I need to click on the card and the filters setting on this synchronize with other graphics.

[image]

On blue, we have a number of tickets opened today. below, we have all types of problems opened. I want to click on the card with opened today and the graphic below shows just the problems opened today.

Comment: The image: https://imgur.com/a/tJDRP4s

Comment: I added it to your post ;)